# How to use inner join inside the update query in SQLite in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I want to update whole table from on query. Following is my update functionality is happened:

1. Database (Database A) stored in the iDevice
2. Temperory Database (Batabase B)  downloads to the device and store in the temp folder inside the device. (Both DB has same database structure)
3. First I attach temp db to device database. Attached db name is SECOND1
4. Then I insert new records from temp db to device folder from following Insert code. It is working fine.

   `INSERT INTO main.fList SELECT * FROM SECOND1.fList WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 FROM main.fList WHERE main.fList.GUID = SECOND1.fList.GUID)`
5. But when I use following code to update it is not working fine. It update same top value for all device db table's rows.

   `UPDATE fList SET Notes = (SELECT SECOND1.fList.Notes FROM SECOND1.fList WHERE SECOND1.fList.GUID = fDefectList.GUID) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SECOND1.fList WHERE SECOND1.fList.GUID = fList.GUID`

I found **SQL query** for bulk update. Following is the code,

```
UPDATE fTempRank7
SET
 fTempRank7.int_key = fRank7.int_key,
 fTempRank7.int_rank6 = fRank7.int_rank6,
 fTempRank7.title = fRank7.title,
 fTempRank7.sequence = fRank7.sequence,
 fTempRank7.lastupdated = fRank7.lastupdated 
FROM
 fTempRank7 INNER JOIN fRank7 ON
 fTempRank7.int_key = fRank7.int_key
```

But in sqlite this code does not work.

Anyone knows *bulk update in sqlite*?

Comment: Why are you setting `fTempRank7.int_key = fRank7.int_key`, if you are also joining on the same condition?

Comment: This is a sample code for SQL. Even without JOIN condition in the SQLIte, syntax error is comming near the '.'

Comment: Please post the exact error you are getting. Near which '.' are you getting error?

Comment: near ".": syntax error:

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not support joins in an UPDATE statement.

When you use a table name without a database name, it refers to the first matching table in the innermost query. In other words, if you use `SECOND1.fList` in a subquery, any other occurrence of `fList` refers to the table in `SECOND1`.

To ensure that you always refer to the correct table, use the database name in all table references.
The main database is always named `main`, so all table references should be either `main.fList` or `SECOND1.fList`.

---

Anyway, if you are updating all columns, you can simplify the update by deleting the rows that would be updated, so that all new data can just be inserted:

```sql
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM fList WHERE GUID IN (SELECT GUID FROM SECOND1.fList);
INSERT INTO fList SELECT * FROM SECOND1.fList;
COMMIT;
```

When you have a UNIQUE constraint on the `GUID` column, this can be simplified into a single statement:

```sql
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO fList SELECT * FROM SECOND1.fList;
```

<sup>And here I don't use `main.` because I know what I'm doing. ☺</sup>

Comment: When I delete existing records before insert (update), will it be a problem for performance ? EX. If I want to update 50 000 records at once.

Comment: That depends. You have to try it.